# How to take into account complex numbers in Matlab ichol() function?

Tags: matlab

When using the function ichol() in Matlab to compute the incomplete Cholesky factorization it ignores the complex part of the matrix. That is, L = ichol(A) is equal to L = ichol(real(A)). Here, matrix A is a complex and sparse matrix.

For example,

```
    [4      2+2i     2+2i
A =  2-2i   7        3-2i
     2-2i   3+2i     3    ]

                 [2      0         0
ichol(A)       =  1      2.45      0
                  1      0.817     1.16]

                 [2      0         0
ichol(real(A)) =  1      2.45      0
                  1      0.817     1.16]

                 [2       0        0
ichol(abs(A)) =   1.41    2.37     0
                  1.41    0.718    0.696]
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I can't generate this sample. Also, the marix A is not in a sparse fomrat. I got the following for `A`:
 `(1, 1) ->  2 + 0i
  (2, 1) ->  1 - 1i
  (3, 1) ->  1 - 1i
  (2, 2) ->  2.23607 + 0.00000i
  (3, 2) ->  0.44721 + 0.89443i
  (3, 3) ->  0 + 0i`

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the Cholseky decomposition only defined for positive definite matrices? Yours is clearly not since `A*[1+3i;1-2i;-5]` gives the zero vector. That said, `real(A)` is positive definite in your example.

That's why if you try `chol` you get:

```
>> chol(A)
Error using chol
Matrix must be positive definite.
```

```
>> chol(real(A))
ans =
    2.0000    1.0000    1.0000
         0    2.4495    0.8165
         0         0    1.1547
```

I'm not exactly sure what `ichol` does. However, the documentation lists as a source the reference

> Manteuffel, T.A. "An incomplete factorization technique for positive definite linear systems." Math. Comput. 34, 473–497, 1980.

which sounds like positive definiteness is still needed.